# How can an .NET Interface contain Data

Tags: c#, vb.net

Based on my Understanding interfaces are just protocol and do not have any implementation.

I'm trying to understand the following code:

This code works

```
  Exception ex = new Exception();
  ex.Data.Add("1", "One");
```

Because `Data` is a property of type `ListDictioaryInternal`(as shown by intelisence)) which implements `IDictionary`.

However, if you right-click on `Data` and go to the definition you see it is defined as:

```
public virtual IDictionary Data { get; }
```

Why `Data` is not defined as `ListDictioaryInternal`?

Comment: By defining a property with an interface it allows you to set it to anything that implements that interface without breaking any code that currently uses it.

Comment: Good point. I was also thinking about this, so can Data be set to something other than ListDictioaryInternal?

Comment: Aslo why intelisense aways show it as ListDictioaryInternal

Comment: If MS decided to change it to be backed by something else they could without breaking code (at least not breaking any code that doesn't cast it)

Comment: It is the debugger who tells you that the object in the Data property is of type ListDictioaryInternal (this tooltip you see is not IntelliSense, it is information provided by the debugger . If you end your debugging session and let IntelliSense tell you the type of the Data property, it will tell you IDictionary...)

Comment: It's worth noting that that `Data` property is declared `virtual`, so that means that anyone who defines their own exception class can override that property and return an object of a type other than `ListDictionaryInternal` if they want, as long as it implements `IDictionary`.

Comment: Intellisense shows you the actual run-time type of the object rather than the type of the property returning that object.

Comment: Perfect! Now, this explains it all!

Comment: Post this as an answer.

Comment: post "It's worth noting that that Data property is declared virtual, so that means that anyone who defines their own exception class can override that property and return an object of a type other than ListDictionaryInternal if they want, as long as it implements IDictionary" as answer

Comment: @ elgonzo nice point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Exception` class defines property `Data` which is of type `IDictionary`. This means that any object that implements that interface can be returned by the getter. In fact, if you dig into the definition, you will see this explained in the comments:

```
// Summary:
//     Gets a collection of key/value pairs that provide additional user-defined information
//     about the exception.
//
// Returns:
//     An object that implements the System.Collections.IDictionary interface and contains
//     a collection of user-defined key/value pairs. The default is an empty collection.
public virtual IDictionary Data { get; }
```

It looks like the internal implementation of the class uses `System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal` as the object that is actually used. If you look at the source code for that class, you will find that it implements the interface in question:

```
internal class ListDictionaryInternal: IDictionary 
{
    //...
}
```

So the interface represents a contract of what an object can do. The actual object returned is a concrete class that implements the interface.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, you can implement an interface explicitly. By doing so the functions are not accessible directly on the class but only trough the interface. This also has the effect that you can implement two interfaces with the same function defined in one class but have that function do different things depending on which interface is used. :-)

Comment: @Magnus: Nice comment. Thank you for adding. I have on occasion used interfaces in this manner. It's not intuitive but it has its uses.

Answer (score 2):

Because [ListDictionaryInternal](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/listdictionaryinternal.cs) implements `IDictionary`, so `IDictionary` is used in compliance with [abstraction](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/230401/confused-about-the-definition-of-abstraction-in-oop).

Comment: @BTFman Yes, you can also see it in the comment `Returns: An object that implements the System.Collections.IDictionary interface and contains a collection of user-defined key/value pairs. The default is an empty collection.`

Comment: @BTFman This is part of OOP abstraction, program to an interface. Hav a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface